# How do I log out of a chrome.identity oauth provider

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth

I'm using [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) to log into a 3rd party oauth provider in an chrome extension.  It works fine for logging in- when I use [launchWebAuthFlow](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) I am presented with the third party login screen and redirected back to my application after the signin flow.

However, I can't find a way to enable log out functionality in my extension.  There doesn't seem to be a function to clear the cached logged in identity.  The next time that launchWebAuthFlow is called, it will automatically log me in as the first user, and not prompt me to log in again.

Is there any way to clear the logged in state of the chrome.identity plugin?

Comment: Can you specify which provider are you talking about (if appropriate)?

Comment: The provider is [untappd](https://untappd.com/api/docs) but my question is more about the [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) api.

Comment: This sequence works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50343218/851957

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75825801/6666348

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am not aware about the specific third party provider. But I faced the similar problem when using Google Oauth with chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(). I could sign in the user, but not sign out using removeCachedAuthToken()

In this case, to logout the user, **I used chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() with Google's logout URL rather than it's oauth URL**

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
    { 'url': 'https://accounts.google.com/logout' },
    function(tokenUrl) {
        responseCallback();
    }
);
```

This worked pretty well.

Comment: Thank you. After weeks of searching, this did the trick for me regarding WordPress OAuth2.

Comment: How do I get this to work for Facebook logout? This isn't working for me :/

Comment: I get an error using this method,  `chrome.runtime.lastError` = `"User interaction required"`

Comment: Additional flag is needed for interactive logout. Please see my answer below for details.

Comment: This sequence works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50343218/851957

Answer (score 17):

I've found that calling these two in the sequence is working:

```
var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + token;
window.fetch(url);

chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({token: token}, function (){
  alert('removed');
});
```

Comment: Note this will logout the user globally; from all pages and Chrome browser. Probably not what you want from an extension.

Comment: No using this method works for me, it didn't logout of entire chrome browser, which happened in launchWebAuthFlow for me.

Answer (score 5):

You should add `prompt=select_account` to your auth URL. Your problem will be solved.

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientId}&response_type=token&scope={scopes}&redirect_uri={redirectURL}&prompt=select_account

Comment: hay lắm con trai của ta

Answer (score 3):

For me, `https://accounts.google.com/logout` does not work. But  `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=TOKEN` work well, using simple `window.fetch(url)`, not with `hrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the identity cache using the `chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken(object details, function callback)` method.
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-removeCachedAuthToken

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question that I have tried that method, but it doesn't work.  I looked in the chrome extension support forums and other users who are using the launchWebAuthFlow report the same [problem](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328876).  The removeCachedAuthToken method seems to only work when using google as the oauth provider; it doesn't seem to work with a third party.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to hit the same problem recently, and I finally solved it by adding `login_hint=<new_user>` and `prompt=consent` in the login URL.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve result only with this implementation

```
  chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': false }, currentToken => {
    if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      // Remove the local cached token
      chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({ token: currentToken }, () => {})

      // Make a request to revoke token in the server
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhr.open('GET', `${googleRevokeApi}${currentToken}`)
      xhr.send()

      // Update the user interface accordingly
      // TODO: your callback
    }
  })
```

Answer (score -2):

If you try **launchWebAuthFlow** to logout but get **User interaction required** error, then you need to add one more flag along with the url:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow (
  {'url': 'https://some-logout-url/',
   'interactive': true },
   function(result) {
     console.log(result);
   }
);
```

Comment: Exactly. Which is most of users will prefer over ERROR. If you like errors more than popups just keep the code from accepted answer :-)

Comment: the popup asks for people to sign in. Which is not what you want when the user clicks to logout. I figured in the end of the day that  more work is involved to get this working.