# chrome.identity.LaunchWebAuthFlow: How to implement logout in a web app using oauth2

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I am working on some client side web app like a chrome extension that needs access to outlook mail and calendar. I followed the instruction on https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted and successfully got access and refresh tokens to retrieve data.

However, I cannot find any way of implementing "logout". The basic idea is to let user sign out and login with a different outlook account. In order to do that, I removed cached tokens, requested access tokens in interactive mode. The login window did pop out, but it took any valid email address, didn't let me input password and finally returned tokens for previous account. So I was not able to really use a different account until the old token expired.

Can anyone please tell me if it is possible to send a request to revoke the tokens so people can use a different account? Thanks!

=========================================================
Update: 
Actually it is the fault of chrome.identity api. I used chrome.identity.LaunchWebAuthFlow to init the auth flow. It caches user's identity but no way to remove it. So we cannot really "logout" if using this api.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the user to https://login.microsoftonline.com/logout.srf

Comment: So it seems the problem of chrome.identity.LaunchWebAuthFlow which I used to start auth flow. It caches user's identity but doesn't provide any way of removing it. Event you type a different account, chrome insists the old one. There is an old thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080632/how-do-i-log-out-of-a-chrome-identity-oauth-provider) talking about this problem, but none of the solutions works.

Comment: It's basically [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328876), go star it.

Comment: I ended up with dumping LaunchWebAuthFlow api for two reasons. The first is as described above; and the second is that it doesn't even have an address bar with the link "https://***" which looks scary. Instead, I just create a new tab with the url for login and listen to redirect event to get the  tokens from redirect url.

Answer (score 0):

I used two logouts via launchWebAuthFlow - first I called the logout link to my app, then secondly, I called the logout link to Google.

```
var options = {
    'interactive': false,
    'url': 'https://localhost:44344/Account/Logout'
}
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(options, function(redirectUri) {});

options = {
    'interactive': false,
    'url': 'https://accounts.google.com/logout'
}
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(options, function(redirectUri) {});
```