# chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow logout/switch user

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I make users login to my chrome extension through my own OAuth2 API which uses google signin, through `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` with `interactive` set to `true`, and it works fine, user is prompted to sign in with google account, I get redirect url in my extension's background script, parse access token from it and everything is fine until I need to logout this user and make it possible to sign with other account.
When I try running `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` with `interactive` set to `true` again, nothing pops up, but redirect url is returned in background and access token is picked up for previously logged in user, so I'm unable to make my users switch account.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the identity cache  usng `chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken` ?

Comment: What do you see in console and Network activity when you redo the WebAuthFlow?

Answer (score 8):

I haven't used chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow, but I think your question is similar to ["How do I log out of a chrome.identity oauth provider"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080632/how-do-i-log-out-of-a-chrome-identity-oauth-provider).

Among the answers:

- use launchWebAuthFlow with the logout url https://accounts.google.com/logout
- revoking the token with https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=TOKEN
- Adding `&prompt=select_account` into the url

As I said, I haven't used launchWebAuthFlow yet, but I wanted to help by showing you an already answered question

Comment: Thanks for effort, but I already read that and probably any other question on forums mentioning this, but none of it works

Comment: Could you show what happens in the console or the url when you try these? 
I know when I'm debugging a Chrome extension I console.log everything and if anything disappears too fast I screenshot it with Shift+Cmd+3 and look at it later. Maybe other people could help a bit more if you show what is happening when you try the different methods