# Revoke OAuth token using chrome.identity and Rail's Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, doorkeeper

I'm trying to use OAuth2 and the chrome.identity API to handle authorization between my Chrome extension and my Rails app using Doorkeeper.

Logging a user in works fine, however I'm having issue with revoking a users token and logging them out. The issue is that for login I pass in the default Doorkeeper GET route to `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`, but for logout Doorkeeper expects a POST request to `/oauth/revoke` yet chrome.identity seems to only work for GET.

Here is a basic example -

```
var clientId = "abc123";
var clientSecret = "xxxxxx";
var redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('provider_cb');

var login_options = {
  'interactive': true,
  'url': 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize' + 
         '?response_type=token' +
         '&client_id=' + clientId +
         '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + 
         '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)
}

chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(login_options, function(redirectUri) {
  var token = redirectUri.match(/(?<=access_token=)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?=[\?|&|\=])/)[0];


  var logout_options = {
    'interactive': false,
    'url': 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/revoke' + 
           '?response_type=code' +
           '&client_id=' + clientId +
           '&client_secret=' + clientSecret +
           '&token=' + token +
           '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)
  }

  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(logout_options, function (redirectUrl) {

  });

});
```

On the logout I get this -

`Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.launchWebAuthFlow: Authorization page could not be loaded.`

Is the solution to mimic Doorkeeper's revoke function in a GET route, or does Chrome have a way to force a logout via POST using `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`?

Comment: I think your can just call the revoke endpoint directly: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke This is what I do in my OAuth 2.0 code but I am not using Chrome Identity. I do believe that Chrome Identity is backed by Google Accounts, so this should work.

Comment: This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27344088/8016720

Comment: @JohnHanley sorry I should've been more clear, I'm using chrome identity for my 3rd-party authentication and am not trying to authenticate with Google Accounts.