# A way to sign off user from a session, but not a chrome browser profile

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Do you know why calling such code for MV2 extension was signing off the user from e.g. GDrive or Gmail, but when using the same for MV3 it just simply does not work?

```
      fetch('https://accounts.google.com/Logout', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors'
      })
```

I am thinking that it is caused by Service Worker used in MV3, where we have simple background page in MV2.

Do you have any advice on how I could achieve that? Sign off user from Google services but not from Chrome browser profile?

I found this [TIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080632/how-do-i-log-out-of-a-chrome-identity-oauth-provider), which is working, but signing me from my profile too.

I also tried adding some additional request headers but without any result. The MV3 code I used is 1:1 as the MV2 code.

All advice are welcome.

Comment: Maybe your sites in MV3 `host_permissions` differ from sites in MV2 `permissions`. Otherwise it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: I have the same `"<all_urls>"` in both cases. I was thinking that changing `cors` to `no-cors` did the work, but it didn't. I am still struggling with it.